# How can I tell which location is the best?

Tags: sampling, multivariate-analysis

I have a list of the scores from various locations on different exams listed below. 
How can I compare the different test and scores to show which location is the best over all?

It would really help if someone could inform which type of test to do and why.  I first thought to use the Wilcoxon signed-rank test, but the data is not in pairs.

```
             English  AP CalcBC    AP PhyscsB   AP Chem     AP Econ 
City      Rank  Score Rank Score  Rank  Score Rank  Score  Rank Score

(Beijing)   6   36.33   4   39.14   1   35.54   1   47.94   3   46.55
(Hefei)     5   38.95   11  26.31   9   18.61   8   27.83   8   30.52
(Hexi)     na      na   8   33.04   na     na   6   37.7    7   32.46
(Huzhou)    4   39.06   1   45.47   na     na   na     na   na     na
(Jiangyin)  9   29.9    9   30      5   24.4    7   31.75   6   36.7
(Jinan)     1   47.72   6   37.2    3   28.91   3   41.55   2   47.94
(Nantong)   3   39.67   5   38.45   2   32.59   5   38.9    4   45.05
(Shanghai)  na     na   3   39.44   6   23.18   2   44.4    5   43.86
(Suzhou)    8   30.19   10  27.5    7   21.75   9   26      9   19.87
(Yangzhou)  2   43.59   2   40.45   4   26.7    4   41.45   1   50.73
(Yixing)    7   33.26   7   35.91   8   21.48   10  24.7    na     na
```

Comment: it seems to me that this is about judgment more than stats.  are all of the subjects equally important?  or do you KNOW that some are more important than others such that you can assign a vector of weights?  if they are all equal and graded on the same scale, why not simply sum them?

Comment: So you are just saying taking the mean of the scores for each site and use that?

Comment: Why do the ranks for 'AP Economics' start with 11? Is this a typo?

Comment: @jokel an artifact of the way markdown does lists: specifically, there was a space at the beginning of the AP Economics line, so markdown assumed that the Econ list was a continuation of the previous list and automatically renumbered it.

Comment: @gung how did you get the data to look like that?

Comment: CV's [Editing help](http://stats.stackexchange.com/editing-help) page guides you through some of the markdown options that are available. To do a code block, you highlight the section & click on the "{}" above the text field. To put the data in a table, I did some quick editing in Excel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a multivariate problem, and there's not a single criterion you can you that will tell you which one is "best" in general without you putting weights on which subjects you think are more/less important. For example, consider a simplification with just two cities and two subjects: Shanghai scores 40 in Math, 50 in Physics; Beijing scores 50 in Math, 40 in Physics. Which is better? It depends on whether you think Math or Physics is more important. Suppose you decided Shanghai was better, and I give you updated scores: the next years Shanghai scores exactly the same, but Beijing scores 50 in math and 40.01 in Physics. Is Shanghai still better, or is Beijing better now? What if Beijing's Physics score had gone up to 41? 42? How high would it have to go before you would decide Beijing were better? This tells you how you weight math vs. physics.

The problem is that you are trying to rank the cities along a single dimension--"goodness"--but you have multivariate data. In order to rank along a single dimension, you have to reduce your data to one dimension, and how you do that depends on how important you think each subject is. Your ranking will end up being according to a weighted average of each city's scores in each subject. If you want to assume that each subject is of the same importance, then you just take the regular average where all subjects are weighted equally.

If you're interested in reading more about the problem, the general topic is multivariate optimization.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not care about the scores of individual subjects (Chemistry, Economics, etc.) you can just average the scores for every city and compare them as suggested in the comment. Otherwise you could use [multinomial logistic regression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_logistic_regression) which allows you to predict a nomial outcome variable ('city' in your case) by your independent variables ('subject' and 'mean score').